Contact Form Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: validatetTextarea is not defined
At the bottom of the code, line 639
$('#form-submit').prop('disabled', false).attr("onclick", "window.location.href='#';");

Once # is replaced with any URL this error appears:

Uncaught ReferenceError: validatetTextarea is not defined

line 626 code:
  else if (!validatetTextarea()) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }   
});

The problem is, when the contact form button is clicked, a blank page appears with the text 'Something Went Wrong'. If # is replaced with google.com or any link, it still display the same error.
// ---------------------------contact-us validation------------------------

// clear form onload page
$(window).on('pageshow', function() {
  $('#contact')[0].reset();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // keypress enter - false
  $('#name, #email, #message').keypress(function (e) {
    let key = e.which;
    if(key == 13) {
        return false;  
    }
  });   

  //-------------------name validation-------------------

  // validate name
  $('#name').on('input blur keydown keyup change', function(){
    validateName();
  });

  let nameVal = false;

  // validation function
  function validateName() {
    let name = document.querySelector('#name');
    let regex = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ0-9.\-_ ]+$/;
    let minLengthName = 2; 
    let maxLengthName  = 30; 
    let regexName = /(.)\1{3}/;
    let firstChar = $("#name").val().charAt(0);

    // check max len
    $('#name').on('keydown keypress', function(e) {
      let val = $(this).val();
      if (val.length >= maxLengthName && e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 46) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });

    // checking for an empty string
    if (name.value.length == 0) {
      $('#name').removeClass('valid');
      $('#name').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_name').text('');
      nameVal = false;
      return false;
    }
    // check first character
    else if (!(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ]/).test(firstChar)) {
      $('#name').removeClass('valid');
      $('#name').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_name').text("The name entered is invalid. The first character must be a letter").css('color', 'red');
      $('#name').addClass('invalid'); 
      nameVal = false;
      return false;
    }
    // length check
    else if ((0 < name.value.length && name.value.length < minLengthName) || (name.value.length > maxLengthName)) {
      $('#name').removeClass('valid');
      $('#name').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_name').text("The name entered is invalid. The name must be between " + minLengthName + " and " + maxLengthName + " characters").css('color', 'red');
      $('#name').addClass('invalid'); 
      nameVal = false;
      return false;
    }        
    // input validation no more than 3 identical characters in a row
    else if (regexName.test($('#name').val())) {
      $('#name').removeClass('valid');
      $('#name').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_name').text("The name entered is invalid. Too many identical characters").css('color', 'red');
      $('#name').addClass('invalid'); 
      nameVal = false;
      return false;
    }
    // checking for valid characters
    else if (!regex.test($('#name').val())) {
      $('#name').removeClass('valid');
      $('#name').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_name').text("The name entered is invalid. The name can only contain letters, numbers, spaces and symbols (._-)").css('color', 'red');
      $('#name').addClass('invalid'); 
      nameVal = false;
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $('#name').removeClass('valid');
      $('#name').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_name').text("The entered name is valid").css('color', 'green');
      $('#name').addClass('valid');
      // check first character
      if (!(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ]/).test(firstChar)) {
        $('#name').removeClass('valid');
        $('#name').removeClass('invalid');
        $('.valid_info_name').text("The name entered invalid. The first character must be a letter").css('color', 'red');
        $('#name').addClass('invalid'); 
        nameVal = false;
        return false;
      }
  
      nameVal = true;
      return true;
    }
  }


  // prohibit entering more than 3 identical characters in a row
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').on('keypress', function(e) {
      let re = /(.)\1{2}/;
      if (re.test($('#name').val())) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });


  // first character can only be [a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯіІїЇєЄ]
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').on('keypress', function(event) {
      let inputName = $("#name");
      let valueName = inputName.val();
      let nameKey = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
      if (valueName.length === 0 && !/[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯіІїЇєЄ]/.test(nameKey)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });


  // allowed chars
  $('#name').on('keypress', function(e) {
    let allowedChars = /[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ0-9'\-.\_ ]/;
    let charCode = (typeof e.which === "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (!allowedChars.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode))) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }      
  });  


  //-------------------email validation-------------------


  var minLength = 8;
  var maxLength = 50;
  var emailRegEx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._\-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
  var input = document.querySelector('#email');

  // check max len
  $('#email').on('keydown keypress', function(e) {
      let val = $(this).val(); 
      if (val.length >= maxLength && e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 46) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  });


  // check deny char    
  function denyChar(infoCallback) {
    $('#email').on('keypress', function(event) {
      let regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_@]/;
      let char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
      if (!regex.test(char)) {
        setTimeout(function() {    
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.valid_info_email').text('Latin letters, numbers and some symbols are allowed in this field').css('color', 'red'); 
            setTimeout(function() {
              infoCallback();
            }, 1000); 
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
      else { 
        infoCallback();      
        return true;
      }
    });
  }


  // validate email
  $('#email').on('input keypress blur keydown keyup change', function() {
    validateEmail();
  }); 

  let emailVal = false;

  function validateEmail() {
    if (input.value.length >= minLength && input.value.length <= maxLength) {  
      let regexFirst = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
      let regexD = /(.)\1{6}/;
      // check char "@"
      if (input.value.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
        let email = $('#email').val();
        let atIndex = email.indexOf('@');
        // check dots 
        if (atIndex >= 0) {
          let domain = email.split('@')[1];
          let numDots = (domain.match(/\./g) || []).length;
          // check more than 2 dots in a row after "@"
          if (/@.*?\.{2,}/.test(email)) {
            $('#email').removeClass('valid');
            $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
            $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Check the address you entered').css('color', 'red');
            $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
            let infoCallback = function() {
              $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Check the address you entered').css('color', 'red');
            };
            denyChar(infoCallback);
            emailVal = false;
            return false;
          }
          // check more than 2 dots after "@"
          else if (numDots >= 3) {
            $('#email').removeClass('valid');
            $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
            $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many dots after "@"').css('color', 'red');
            $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
            let infoCallback = function() {
              $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many dots after "@"').css('color', 'red');
            };
            denyChar(infoCallback);
            emailVal = false;
            return false;
          }
          // check first char
          else if (!regexFirst.test($('#email').val().charAt(0))) {
            $('#email').removeClass('valid');
            $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
            $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
            $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
            let infoCallback = function() {
              $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
            };
            denyChar(infoCallback);
            emailVal = false;
            return false;
          } 
          // check duplicates
          else if (regexD.test($('#email').val())) {
            $('#email').removeClass('valid');
            $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
            $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
            $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
            let infoCallback = function() {
              $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
            };
            denyChar(infoCallback);
            emailVal = false;
            return false;
          }
          else {
            // checking emailRegEx validation
            if (emailRegEx.test($('#email').val())) {
              // check first char
              if (!regexFirst.test($('#email').val().charAt(0))) {
                $('#email').removeClass('valid');
                $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
                $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
                $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
                let infoCallback = function() {
                  $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
                };
                denyChar(infoCallback);
                emailVal = false;
                return false;
              } 
              // check duplicates
              else if (regexD.test($('#email').val())) {
                $('#email').removeClass('valid');
                $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
                $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
                $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
                let infoCallback = function() {
                  $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
                };
                denyChar(infoCallback);
                emailVal = false;
                return false;
              }
              else {
                $('#email').removeClass('valid');
                $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
                $('.valid_info_email').text('The entered address is valid').css('color', 'green');
                $('#email').addClass('valid');
                let infoCallback = function() {
                  $('.valid_info_email').text('The entered address is valid').css('color', 'green');
                };
                denyChar(infoCallback);
                emailVal = true;
                return true;     
              }
            }
            else {
              $('#email').removeClass('valid');
              $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
              $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid').css('color', 'red');
              $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
              let infoCallback = function() {
                $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid').css('color', 'red');
              };
              denyChar(infoCallback);
              emailVal = false;
              return false;
            }
          }
        }     
      }   
      // check first char
      else if (!regexFirst.test($("#email").val().charAt(0))) {
        $('#email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
        $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
        let infoCallback = function() {
          $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
        };
        denyChar(infoCallback);
        emailVal = false;
        return false;
      } 
      // check duplicates
      else if (regexD.test($('#email').val())) {
        $('#email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
        $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
        let infoCallback = function() {
          $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
        };
        denyChar(infoCallback);
        emailVal = false;
        return false;
      }
      else {
        $('#email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('.valid_info_email').text('The entered address is invalid, please enter "@"').css('color', 'red');
        $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
        let infoCallback = function() {
          $('.valid_info_email').text('The entered address is invalid, please enter "@"').css('color', 'red');
        };
        denyChar(infoCallback);
        emailVal = false;
        return false;
      }   
    }           
    else if (input.value.length == 0) {
        $('#email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('.valid_info_email').text('');
        let infoCallback = function() {
          $('.valid_info_email').text('');
        };
        denyChar(infoCallback);
        emailVal = false;
        return false;
    }
    else {
      if ((input.value.length > 0 && input.value.length < minLength) || input.value.length > maxLength) {
        $('#email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid, valid from ' + minLength + ' to ' + maxLength + ' characters').css('color', 'red');
        $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
        let infoCallback = function() {
          $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid, valid from ' + minLength + ' to ' + maxLength + ' characters').css('color', 'red');
        };
        denyChar(infoCallback);
        let regexFirst = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
        let regexD = /(.)\1{6}/;
        // check first char
        if (!regexFirst.test($("#email").val().charAt(0))) {
          $('#email').removeClass('valid');
          $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
          $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
          $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
          let infoCallback = function() {
            $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. The first character can only be a letter or a number').css('color', 'red');
          };
          denyChar(infoCallback);
          emailVal = false;
          return false;
        } 
        // check duplicate
        else if (regexD.test($('#email').val())) {
          $('#email').removeClass('valid');
          $('#email').removeClass('invalid');
          $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
          $('#email').addClass('invalid'); 
          let infoCallback = function() {
            $('.valid_info_email').text('The address entered is invalid. Too many identical characters').css('color', 'red');
          };
          denyChar(infoCallback);
          emailVal = false;
          return false;
        }

        emailVal = false;
        return false;       
      }
    }
  }
  

  // input parameters
  $(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#email').on("keypress", function(event) {
      let input = $("#email");
      let value = input.val();
      let key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
      // first character can only be [a-zA-Z0-9]
      if (value.length === 0 && !/[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      // starting from the second, you can enter [a-zA-Z0-9.-_]
      if (value.length === 1 && !/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]/.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      // starting from the third character, you can enter [a-zA-Z0-9.\-_@]
      if (value.length >= 2 && !/[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_@]/.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      // the input cannot contain two or more dots in a row (for example, '..' or '....')
      if (key === "." && value.slice(-1) === ".") {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }

      // in the input, the limit on the number of consecutive identical characters is up to 5
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#email').on('input', function() {
          let value = $(this).val();
          let regex = /(.)\1{6}/;
          
          if (regex.test(value)) {
            $(this).val(value.slice(0, -1));
          }
        });
      });
    
      // after "@" the first character can only be entered [a-zA-Z0-9], starting from the second one can be entered [a-zA-Z0-9.-]
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#email').on('keypress', function(event) {
          let key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
          let value = $(this).val();  

          // if the character "@" is entered, limit the input of the first character after "@"
          if (value.indexOf("@") !== -1 && value.indexOf(".") === -1 && value.slice(-1) === "@" && !/[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }

          // after the first character after "@", allow letters, numbers, dots, hyphens, or underscores
          if (value.indexOf("@") !== -1 && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")+2) !== -1 && /[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]/.test(value.slice(-1)) && !/[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]/.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }

          // if a dog is found and the entered period is found after it, only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9.\-_] are allowed
          if (value.indexOf("@") !== -1 && value.indexOf(".") !== -1 && value.indexOf(".") > value.indexOf("@") && !/[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]/.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
          
          // if a dog is found, only 2 dots can be entered after it
          if (value.indexOf("@") !== -1 && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")+1) !== -1 && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")+1) !== value.lastIndexOf(".") && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")+1) !== -1 && !/[a-zA-Z]/.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // if a point is found, allow input /[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]/
            if (value.indexOf("@") !== -1 && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")+1) !== -1 && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")+1) === value.lastIndexOf(".") && !/[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]/.test(key)) {
              event.preventDefault();    
              return false;
            }
            // if the second entered point is found after the dog, only characters [a-zA-Z] are allowed
            if (value.indexOf("@") !== -1 && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")) !== -1 && value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf(".", value.indexOf("@")+1)) !== -1 && !/[a-zA-Z]/.test(key)) {
              event.preventDefault();
              return false;
            }
                       
            return false;
          }     
        });
      });    
              
      
      // allow enter "@" only one times
      $(document).ready(function() {
        let inputField = $('#email');
        inputField.on('keypress', function(e) {
          let currentValue = $(this).val();
          if (e.which === 64 && currentValue.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      });
    

      // allowed chars
      $('#email').on('keypress', function(e) {
          let allowedChars = /[a-zA-Z0-9._@-]/;
          let charCode = (typeof e.which === "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
          if (!allowedChars.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode))) {
          e.preventDefault();
          }      
      });  
    });

  });
  
  //-------------------textarea validation-------------------
  
  // validate textarea
  $('#message').on('blur keydown keyup change', function() {
    validateTextarea();
  });

  let textareaVal = false;

  // validation function of Textarea
  function validateTextarea() {
    let message = $('#message').val();
    let regex_textarea = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ0-9., \-'_]+$/;
    let maxLengthMessage = 500;

    $('#message').on('keydown keypress', function(e) {
      let val = $(this).val();
      if (val.length >= maxLengthMessage && e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 46) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });

    // checking for an empty field
    if (message == 0) {
      $('#message').removeClass('valid');
      $('#message').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_message').text("");
      textareaVal = false;
      return false;
    } 
    // if the field contains illegal characters
    else if (!regex_textarea.test(message)) {
      $('#message').removeClass('valid');
      $('#message').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_message').text("Invalid characters entered").css('color', 'red');
      $('#message').addClass('invalid'); 
      textareaVal = false;
      return false;
    } 
    // if the field contains more than 500 characters
    else if (message.length > 500) {
      $('#message').removeClass('valid');
      $('#message').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_message').text("The maximum message length is 500 characters").css('color', 'red');
      $('#message').addClass('invalid'); 
      textareaVal = false;
      return false;
    } 
    else { 
      $('#message').removeClass('valid');
      $('#message').removeClass('invalid');
      $('.valid_info_message').text("The entered message is valid").css('color', 'green');
      $('#message').addClass('valid');
      textareaVal = true;
      return true;
    }

  }


  // allowed characters
  $('#message').on('keypress', function(e) {
    let allowedChars = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ0-9., \-'_]/;
    let charCode = (typeof e.which === "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (!allowedChars.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode))) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }      
  }); 

  // -----------------------------------------------------------
  
  // remove emoji
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ0-9.\-_ ]+$/;
    var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._@-]+$/;
    var messageRegex = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ0-9., \-'_]+$/;
  
    $('#name').on('input keydown keyup change', function() {
      removeInvalidChars($(this), nameRegex);
    });
  
    $('#email').on('input keydown keyup change', function() {
      removeInvalidChars($(this), emailRegex);
    });
  
    $('#message').on('input keydown keyup change', function() {
      removeInvalidChars($(this), messageRegex);
    });
  
    function removeInvalidChars(input, regex) {
      var str = input.val();
      str = str.replace(/[^\w\s.\-@а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇєЄ,']/g, '');
      input.val(str);
    }
  });
  
  // -----------------------------------------------------------
  
  // event handler on form submission
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // cancel form submission if validation fails
    if (!validateName()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (!validateEmail()) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    else if (!validatetTextarea()) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
    }   
  });
  

  // form validation
  $('#contact').on('input blur keyup change', function() {
    validateEmail();
    validateName();
    validateTextarea();

    if (emailVal === true && nameVal === true && textareaVal === true) {
      $('#form-submit').prop('disabled', false).attr("onclick", "window.location.href='#';"); 

      $('#name, #email, #message').keypress(function(e) {
        if (emailVal === true && nameVal === true && textareaVal === true) {
          var key = e.which;
          if(key == 13) {
            $('#form-submit').click();
            return false;  
          }
        }
      });   
      return true;
    } 
    else {
      $('#form-submit').prop('disabled', true);

      $('#name, #email, #message').keypress(function(e) {
        let key = e.which;
        if(key == 13) {
            return false;  
        }
      });  
      
      return false;
    }  
  });
  
});    

I changed return false/true in a few locations, but nothing helped. I've reverted it to the original in this post. I can't understand why the form won't work. Where is the error? Thanks.

where is the error... The error is exactly where the error message says it is. validatetTextarea is just a typo - the name of your function is validateTextarea. So change else if (!validatetTextarea()) { to else if (!validateTextarea()) {.

I'm amazed that you can write that much code for validating a form. Not that I have the solution for your issue, but here is a tutorial on using the build-in form validation: Client-side form validation

Good catch, but still not working, now without providing an error. Geez, well the complete contact form is awesome, but something is not working.

OK so...what exact behaviour does it exhibit now? Have you done any further debugging? This is an absolute mountain of code just for a contact form. Also , you haven't shown us the html page this is attached to, where the form itself is, so we can't run this for ourselves to see how it behaves. Therefore it's hard to diagnose anything when there's no longer an error report, and there's no other description of what happens.

Yeah, got ya. It shows nothing, apart from on screen display error, which is the same (something went wrong) here is the whole form https://pastebin.com/s6pDKfL7 Thanks for taking a look bro!

Thanks. So, in that pastebin you've shown us some HTML code, and then separately some CSS and JS code. But there's nothing in that HTML  which would cause the JS or CSS file to be included and used in the HTML document. How are you actually, in reality, including the JS code into your page? Normally such a script would either be inline inside a <script tag, or mentioned via a URL (also via a <script tag). Presumably you have, in reality, included it somehow or else the earlier mentioned error could not have occurred. But please show us a [mre] of the issue with your real code.

For the sake of charity I assumed you have actually included the JS and CSS properly. Then I made a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j52o3bg7/ . As far as I can see your code works perfectly. It stops the user submitting the form until all fields are filled in and the email address looks valid, and then it allows the submission. Of course if you don't submit the form to a real script you then get an error, but that's not the fault of any of the jQuery code you've shown us.

Yes, everything is connected, JS stored separately, but added to html where is css too. You are right, everything works, but in the JS, after form is successfully submitted, I need to redirect user to a webpage. Instead, there is a 404 error page etc. So, it has to be a JS problem? Well, I have no real script to collect the data yet. You mean it won't work because of that? As of now, I only uploaded what I shared here. My goal is just to have a working form for now. If you don't mind, please guide me how to end this drama. Thank you for taking your time for me.

Your actual form, as we've shown, is working perfectly. I don't know what you want to do with the data it collects though? Perhaps you want to store it in a database somewhere? Or send an email containing the information submitted? Or both? Or something else. All of these tasks though would require you to have a server-side script which receives the HTTP POST request (which is generated when you submit the form) and processes the data according to your needs. You can't do those things from a browser directly. After it's done processing, the server-side can redirect the browser to another page.

Thank you. My goal was a cool contact form rather than any data collecting. I might want to collect the emails, that piece of data would be useful. So I will have to connect this script to a php file script that process the information and then another page can be successfully dsplayed. I hope I got it right. Could you please give me some basic example of how is this done, the most simple one, so I can see if I can get that page to load in the end. Many thanks.

It doesn't have to be php, any server side language could do it. But php is a reasonable choice. There must be a billion php contact form examples out there showing how to process form data and put that data into an email. I doubt the world really needs another. Start from a couple of examples, just adapt them to the specific fields your form sends when it submits

Yeah I found some online, it's easy. Well thank you once again for the clarity.
